# Modifications in index.jsp doesn't appear when running the project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

This is my `index.jsp` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Bank application</th></tr>
</table>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Bank Account Balance</legend>
  <form action="show-balance">
    Customer ID (id001, id002, id003):
    <input type="text" name="customerId"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Balance"/>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Random Number</legend>
  <form action="random-number"> 
    Range:  <input type="text" name="range"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Number">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Registration</legend>
  <form action="register"> 
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Prime Number</legend>
  <form action="find-prime"> 
    Length: <input type="text" name="primeLength"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate Prime">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body></html>
```

It looks something like this :

[image: 123]

But when I try to do some modifications to `index.jsp` , for example let's take the last `legend`:

```
<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Prime QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ Number</legend>
  <form action="find-prime QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ "> 
    Length: <input type="text" name="primeLength"><br>
    <input type="suQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ bmit" value="Calculate PrimQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ e">
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

I still get the same page .

What's wrong with it ? any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're clearing the browser cache, i.e. use ctrl + f5 rather than just f5. Other than that these things tend to be dependent on your particular dev setup.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you mean by `do some modifications`.  Are you re-compiling and restarting your app server after you make those changes?  If not, are you simply editing the jsp page where it resides in your project?  If so, there's no reason to expect the changes to be detected by the deployed webapp.

Comment: @jahroy: I change the `jsp` file inside of Eclipse , then , I compile the whole thing again . Afterwards I hit `ctrl+F11` in Eclipse , and I get the same page .

Comment: @jahroy: I'm good , thanks . Your suggestions worked out great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
1. Stop the web/app server.
2. Delete the app/war from the webapps dir
3. Start web/app server.
4. Re-deploy your app/war file.
```

Answer (score 2):

- Have you tried restarting the app server?
- Is there any message in your app server logs?
- What about the pre-compiled JSP? Can you see the corresponding .java file? If so, does it have your changes too?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a web application, your JSPs are copied to a new location.

Then they are either pre-compiled or compiled the first time somebody visits the page (based on app server configuration).

If you modify a JSP page in your project, there is no reason to expect the corresponding JSP to reflect your changes unless you re-deploy.

There is one exception:

- You can edit the JSP `in-place` in the location to which it gets copied on deployment.

This is generally not a good idea, because your changes won't be made to your project.